# Source-level definition of `seq` in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to understand `seq` in Haskell. I've got some understanding of `seq` in English, so now I'd like to read its implementation.

However, [the source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.9.0/docs/src/GHC.Prim.html#seq) says

```hs
infixr 0 `seq`
seq :: a -> b -> b
seq = seq
```

How can I read this? It this an infinitely recursive definition? I suspect it's not, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`seq` cannot be implemented in plain Haskell. That is a "dummy" definition. It is "replaced" with the actual `seq` behavior by GHC. So the real implementation (so to speak) of `seq` is inside the compiler.

To put it another way: If we ignore the name of the function in that code snippet, that definition has no relationship to `seq`. The compiler sees the name "`seq`" (and maybe the fact that it's defined in that specific module; I'm not sure about the details) and that tells it to replace the definition with the actual `seq` behavior during compilation.

Answer (score 3):

The file you linked starts with

> {- This is a generated file (generated by genprimopcode). It is not
> code to actually be used. Its only purpose is to be consumed by
> haddock. -}

hence it is only generated so that it can in turn cause documentation to be generated.

Every single definition in the file is given by a dummy recursion `x = x`. That is not the real definition, but only a placeholder.

Haskell's primitives in `GHC.Prim` like `seq` can not be simply implemented in a Haskell module (otherwise they would not be called *primitives*). Instead, they are handled in a special way during compilation.

Comment: "Haskell's primitives in `GHC.Prim` like `seq` can not be simply implemented in a Haskell module" `seq !_ = id`?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Sure :) I might be wrong here, but IIRC historically `seq` predated bang patterns (& strictness annotations). Anyway, it should be possible to define `seq` in terms of bang patterns (like you just did) and vice versa, so we have to take at least one of them as a primitive.